# Contar ocorrências em tuplas

Tags: python

Tenho um problema que até é simples mas não estou a conseguir chegar à solução.

Tenho uma lista de tuplas, por exemplo:

```
lista = [('x',2,3),('y',4,5),('x',6,7),('z',8,9)]
```

O que eu quero é que ele me conte quantas vezes aparece o `x`,`y` e `z` nessa lista. Neste caso o `x` aparece `2` vezes e o `y` e `z` aparecem `1` vez, logo deveria me retornar uma lista com `[2,1,1]`.

E eu queria resolver isto com `map` ou `reduce`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar o excelente [`Counter` de `collections`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html):

```
from collections import Counter
lista_contagens = Counter(map(lambda: x, x[0], lista))
# Isto imprime as contagens
print(lista_contagens.values())
```

Comment: o `x` dentro do lambda representa o que? Diz-me que nao esta definido

Comment: já resolvi, ficava : `lista_contagens = Counter(map(lambda x: x[0], lista))` mas isto nao me devolve o lista como eu queria: `[2,1,1]`

Comment: Atualizei a resposta.

Comment: É isso mesmo, Obrigada!

Answer (score 1):

Contagem de palavras é o exemplo básico de map/reduce. Para esse seu caso, apenas adapte a etapa de map e implemente o reduce tradicional.
Segue um exemplo para mapper:

mapper.py

```
lista = [('x',2,3),('y',4,5),('x',6,7),('z',8,9)]
for i in lista:
    print '%s\t%s' % (i[0], '1')
```

Segue uma documentação com exemplo completo:
http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/writing-an-hadoop-mapreduce-program-in-python/